# Add a [tour] shortcut to comments and chat

Tags: feature-request, comments, short-links

Shorthands in comments are something we have for a while now. If you add `[help]` to a comment, it expands to [help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help), if you type `[about]`, you get [about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about), etc.

Since the new top bar [calls it "Tour"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1lS6.jpg), rather than "about", I suggest that we add [tour] as a shorthand for comments, Much like we have [about] and [help].

Comment: Read that 3 times. Sorry - may be it's me, but I can't get the sense of such change

Comment: @AlmaDo: Currently, when you type `[help]` in a comment, it reads [help]. If you type `[tour]` you get [tour]. Since the top bar calls it a "tour" now, and not "the about page", I suggest we add [tour] to keep things consistent (when you refer a user to take the [tour]).

Comment: @AlmaDo: I edited to clarify, tell me if you understood it now

Comment: Yes, got it now. Never knew about that possibility. [tour] (not working), [help] (yay, working)